# Display user profile with unique url (jsp-servlet, MySql)

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

So I am having a web app which allows me to register and login using jsp and servlets. I am connecting to the MySql database. 
After user login servlet returns to the index.jsp, which is my home page.
So now I need to make at insex.jsp something like:

```
<li><a href="UserProfile.jsp/<%=lg.getUsername()%>">Your Profile</a></li>
```

And my main problem is to understand how to make able to link UserProfile.jsp to after slash link? Maybe I should link to the UserProfile servlet first to retrieve all the iser data using Java Beans and then return to page UserProfile.jsp/username with all the parameters?
But still cannot understand how to link jsp page to after slash information.
Any example would be great! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass the parameter to the servlet , it should be as below ,

```
<li><a href="UserProfile?userName=<%=lg.getUsername()%>">Your Profile</a></li>
```

Assuming `UserProfile` is the servlet. you can get the value for the `userName` in `doGet()` as below,

```
request.getParameter("userName");
```

Once you have fetched the data for the user in the servlet, forward the response to the `UserProfile.jsp` using [`RequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html).

Comment: Thank you! So first of all I need to connect to servlet and pass the parameter to it. After that I need to redirect to UserProfile.jsp/username page. But it will show an error, as I can only redirect to UserProfile.jsp and I do not have this /username url ending in it. So how to make that? Should I create a some kind of folder for each user? Or it can be just a database information. Or I just need to link to the UserProfile.jsp and somehow imitate this .../username ending in the url?

Comment: Why do you need the username ending with the URL . even if you need so pass the value to the url . something like `"url/username="+username` in the servlet

Comment: If suppose that I want to have many users in my web app. I want to have option to see not only my own profile, but also the profile of other users. So I need to have a url which looks like: http://www.localhost:9090/UserProfile.jsp/username
So I do not know how to link not to UserProfile.jsp, but exactly to UserProfile.jsp/username and where to store it?

Comment: @code4fun did you ever figure this out in the end ?